# Can i use Anker charger to power 2 Raspberry Pis

Tags: pi-zero-w-2, pi-5

Is it safe to power a Raspberry Pi 5 8GB and a Pi Zero 2 W with an Anker 735 GanPrime charger?

Comment: does it provide the correct voltage, and is it able to provide the required current without a voltage sag?

Comment: Maybe not... review the specs, and don't find a single word re the output voltage. "Charging" is different then "powering".

Answer (score -1):

It's 100% safe to do so. You may get low voltage warnings on the Pi5. f you're not doing anything too computationally demanding you won't even get that (benchmarking and the like). I would power the zero from the USB on the Pi5. You could even put the zero into USB Ethernet Gadget mode and SSH via the Pi5.

TLDR: Yeah it's fine.